# DataWeave combine arrays in alternating order

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio

If I have arrays `[A,B,C]`and `[1,2,3]`
How can I combine them to be `[A,1,B,2,C,3]`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming both arrays have the same length:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var a1=["A","B","C"]
var a2=[1,2,3]
---
a1 flatMap [$, a2[$$]]
```

Output:

```
[
  "A",
  1,
  "B",
  2,
  "C",
  3
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [zip](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-zip)

**DW**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var a1=["A","B","C"]
var a2=[1,2,3]
---
flatten(a1 zip a2)
```

**Output**

```
[
  "A",
  1,
  "B",
  2,
  "C",
  3
]
```